# Mac OSX PackageMaker sort/arrange content

Tags: macos, sorting, packagemaker

Using Mac OSX 10.6 PackageMaker...

...Can anyone tell me, how can i sort/arrange contents of my package (Choices, Packages, etc) **AFTER** creating them?

Scenario:

```
1.Create a choice "bar" at root level
2.Create a choice "foo" at root level
```

After doing, running installer, i noticed is displayed like:

```
bar
foo
```

What i need:

```
foo
bar
```

Changes on raw mode dont commit :S ?

Comment: As discussed on installer-dev@lists.apple.com, PackageMaker lacks this feature (among others)

Answer (score 0):

The way I get around this is to go to 'Project'->'Raw Editing Mode', then modify the 'id' item in the 'choice' sections of the XML code.

It's a hassle but it does work.